# How to - if div has child div, expand this div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, if-statement

So if an accordion div has information/a body, how can I alert this? The information is dynamically loaded, and if the div has information (not all do) - it looks like this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"></div>
    <div id="collapse_1" class="accordion-body collapse"></div>
</div>
```

...other wise it's

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"></div>
</div>
```

so, if the icon for the div I'm clicking has a child with the class .accordion-body...how can I use jQuery to traverse this? So far my idea was:

```
$('.accordion-toggle > i').click(function () {
    if ($(this).closest('.panel-default').has('div.accordion-body')) {
        //var open = $(this).toggleClass('fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-up');
        //$.toggle('open');
        alert('expandable section')
    } else {
        alert('nothing to expand')
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.has()` returns a jQuery object so it will be truthy always... you need to check `.has(...).length`

Comment: where is the `.accordion-toggle > i` elements placed

Comment: You probably don't want to use a click function--there are other ways to trigger accordions which may bypass your function. Instead, use a callback on the accordion show event.

Comment: within the .panel-heading

Comment: Also, I don't think this will result in a good user experience. You don't want to be alerting people to death, and if there's no content in the body, it would be better to put your 'empty' messaging there and do the expand anyway. A click with no result is confusing. Why not place a default 'empty' message there that gets overwritten by the body?

Comment: The alert is for testing. I just need to know this is reading correctly before I move on.

Comment: You need to put the .accordian-toggle HTML. Without this it's hard to see what you want.

Comment: That said, I think it's simply as @ArunPJohny, says. You just need to add `.has('div.accordion-body').length > 0`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.accordion-toggle > i').click(function () {                   
    if ($(this).closest(".panel-default").children("div").hasClass('accordion-body')) {
       //var open = $(this).toggleClass('fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-up');
       alert('expandable section')
    }else{
       alert('nothing to expand')
    }
});
```

Comment: `.children("div.accordion-body").length > 0` would prob be more efficient. `.hasClass` has to test every child in the above